# Overlap Divs to display content (In Centre) and (In right) Side

Tags: bootstrap-4

Hi I am trying to display first content in the centre and the second content on the right hand side on the same line.

I am using below snippet to achieve but this is creating another line which is not expected.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="text-center">TestText</div>
        <div class="text-right">14/08/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="text-right col-6">TestText</div>
        <div class="text-right col-6">14/08/18</div>
</div>
```

You need to set the two divs to col-6 but then right align the first text div to `text-align: right` - You also need to get rid of the `col-12` as it's not needed in this instance - hope this helps